# Canvas native methods eating lot of RAM

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, memory-leaks, html5-canvas

I'm writing a software that can perform operations on HTML5 Canvas based on single pixels. Basically I'm getting all the pixels, updating the values of RGB and writing them back using native methods getImageData, createImageData and putImageData.

While doing some tests I've found that my software uses a lot of RAM, much more than the quantity used by javascript. So I've created [this github repo](https://github.com/dumaron/canvasMemoryTest/commits/master) to remove one by one every element that can cause memory consumption and I've found that it was caused by these native methods. I know this software can be improved a lot, but this does not explain this effect. Take it as an example.

You can see the effects of the RAM consumption by changing to different commits: the first is the worst, the second-last the best. By navitaging the different commits you can see that the only version where the used memory seems "explainable" is [this commit](https://github.com/dumaron/canvasMemoryTest/commit/95a8118bdafd62c651d2b2a9f34e34f342601a9d), where I've removed all the references to canvas native methods.

The intresting thing is that the memory used is not catched by the memory profiler: it's like there's some memory used by chrome not dependent by my javascript. Try running [this commit](https://github.com/dumaron/canvasMemoryTest/commit/11db3dc6b235b95189b1bcb15e83288df39e6602) and see amount of memory with your local task manager (htop, for instance) and the google debug tools, js heap voice. There's a huge difference.

All this tests are done on Chrome 47; Firefox seems to does't have this problem.

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong? Why every call of these methods don't release the memory but continue accumulating, generating a memory leak?

Comment: Would be interesting to know what engine this what tested with, V8 (Chrome), SpiderMonkey (Firefox), Chakra (IE)?

Comment: You are right. I've tested my software on chrome 47. Seems that Firefox doesn't have this problem, but I prefer investigate more about that.

Comment: *Possible (probable?) use of memory:* While I haven't looked at your linked code, `.getImagData` is memory hungry because it grabs an array of pixel data with each "get" and because none of its work is delegated to the GPU. It may take a while for the GC to recycle -- and yes, GCs on different browsers will behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred answer for this one is to *pull out a profiler and check*.

Now eyeballing your code, I see this:

```
pixels.forEach(function(pixel) {
  var interval = 1, x, y, square=[];
  for (x=-interval; x<interval; x++)
    for (y=-interval; y<interval; y++) {
      var tmp = getPixel(pixel.x + x, pixel.y + y);
      if (tmp) square.push(tmp);
    }
});
```

For each pixel, it's creating an array `square`. There's your memory hog right there. As the number of pixels grow, you create the same amount of arrays. I'm not sure where `square` is being used. It's just accepting values.

Additionally, you have a 3-level loop there. And we all know `forEach` is slower than your regular loop. You might want to change your logic to avoid this.

As for when the GC kicks in, that depends on the browser. You can't really tell when it kicks in, but you can certainly avoid it by keeping an eye on how you create stuff like objects.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I am profiling my code with chrome debug tools, using CPU profiling and taking timeline with heap allocation memory.
The problemi with this approach is that the js heap profiler doesn't explain the memory consumption generated by using native methods. There is a memory used by chrome not dependent by my javascript I think, and my code try to prove that.
I don't agree with you analisys: in [this commit](https://github.com/dumaron/canvasMemoryTest/commit/11db3dc6b235b95189b1bcb15e83288df39e6602) I removed the for and the square part, but the memory used is still unexplicable.

Comment: @Duma It would be best to also put your code and findings in your post :)